# Действительно - вводное слово?

Tags: вводные-слова

Ведь действительно предприниматель, организуя свой собственный бизнес, выступая руководителем собственного бизнеса, ставит перед собой эти три цели.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что здесь - не вводное. Можно заменить на "по-настоящему", "по сути".

> Не смешивать с употреблением в роли члена предложения (в знач. «на
>   самом деле, подлинно»)!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А у меня закралась мысль, что в роли члена предложения "действительно" может выступать только перед сказуемым, например, глаголом, прилагательным. А в этом примере не так, значит, может, это вводное слово? Возможно, я плохо обдумал возможные примеры и неправ, но в Ваших двух примерах глаголы после него как раз.

Comment: Запятую почему-то хочется ставить только после этого слова - вводного или не вводного...

Comment: Согласен! Только не перед. Может, даже если оно и правда вводное, оно объединяется с частицей "ведь"?

Comment: Алёнка и Тёмочка! С запятой изменится смысл. Типо "ведь, по правде говоря, предприниматель..."

Comment: А разве не такой смысл там и есть, Галина? Я бы даже сказал: "И в самом деле, предприниматель..." Разве не это имеется в виду? На самом деле, это скорее Алёнке вопрос.)